# How to reduce the time complexity of bucket filling program?

Tags: java, c++, algorithm

I was solving a problem which states following:

There are n buckets in a row. A gardener waters the buckets. Each day he waters the buckets between positions *i* and *j* (inclusive). He does this for *t* days for different *i* and *j*.

Output the volume of the waters in the buckets assuming initially zero volume and each watering increases the volume by `1`.

**Input**: first line contains *t* and *n* seperated by spaces.
The next *t* lines contain *i* and *j* seperated by spaces.

**Output**: a single line showing the volume in the *n* buckets seperated by spaces.

### Example:

**Input:**

2 2
1 1
1 2

**Output:**

2 1

**Constraints:**

0 <= t <= 10<sup>4</sup>; 1 <= n <= 10<sup>5</sup>

I tried this problem. But I use O(n*t) algorithm. I increment each time the bucket from i to j at each step. But this shows time limit error. Is there any efficient algorithm to solve this problem. A small hint would suffice.

P.S: I have used C++ and Java as tags bcoz the program can be programmed in both the languages.

Comment: Parsing the user input and printing the output is probably going to take more time than your calculations...

Comment: No there are only at most 11 line of input...Please check the problem

Comment: Ah, I see. The 10⁵ is the problem.

Comment: Wait, what? Now t≤10⁴. That's **way different** from t<10!

Comment: @DaoWen actually I edited the question..the running time is n*t..sorry for that and thanks for helping me figuring out that..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of remembering the amount of water in each bucket, remember the difference between each bucket and the previous one.

Comment: then at each step we would have to increment d[i] and d[j+1], where d is the difference array. Is this correct?

Comment: How will you know the amount of water in each bucket?

Comment: @Bhushi make `d[i] + 1` and `d[j+1]-1`

Answer (score 1):

have two lists of the intervals, one sorted by upper, one by lower bound

then iterate over n starting with a volume v of 0.

```
On each iteration over n
  check if the next interval starts at n
    if so increase v by one and check the next interval.
  do the same for the upper bounds but decrease the volume
  print v
repeat with the next n
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the key observation here is that you need to figure out a way to represent your (possibly) 10<sup>5</sup> buckets without actually allocating space for each and every one of them, and tracking them separately. You need to come up with a **sparse representation** to track your buckets, and the water inside.

The fact that your input comes in ranges gives you a good hint: you should probably make use of ranges in your sparse representation. You can do this by just tracking the buckets on the ends of each range.

I suggest you do this with a linked list. Each list node will contain 2 pieces of information:

1. a bucket number
2. the amount of water in that bucket

You assume that all buckets between the current bucket and the next bucket have the same volume of water.

Here's an example:

```
Input:
5 30
1 5
4 20
7 13
25 30
19 27
```

Here's what would happen on each step of the algorithm, with step 1 being the initial state, and each successive step being what you do after parsing a line.

1. <kbd>1:0</kbd>→`NULL` (all buckets are 0)
2. <kbd>1:1</kbd>→<kbd>6:0</kbd>→`NULL` (1-5 have 1, rest are 0)
3. <kbd>1:1</kbd>→<kbd>4:2</kbd>→<kbd>6:1</kbd>→<kbd>21:0</kbd>→`NULL` (1-3 have 1, 4-5 have 2, 6-20 have 1, rest have 0)
4. <kbd>1:1</kbd>→<kbd>4:2</kbd>→<kbd>6:1</kbd>→<kbd>7:2</kbd>→<kbd>14:1</kbd>→<kbd>21:0</kbd>→`NULL`
5. <kbd>1:1</kbd>→<kbd>4:2</kbd>→<kbd>6:1</kbd>→<kbd>7:2</kbd>→<kbd>14:1</kbd>→<kbd>21:0</kbd>→<kbd>25:1</kbd>→`NULL`
6. <kbd>1:1</kbd>→<kbd>4:2</kbd>→<kbd>6:1</kbd>→<kbd>7:2</kbd>→<kbd>14:1</kbd>→<kbd>19:2</kbd>→<kbd>21:1</kbd>→<kbd>25:2</kbd>→<kbd>28:1</kbd>→`NULL`

You should be able to infer from the above example that the complexity with this method is actually *O(t<sup>2</sup>)* instead of *O(n×t)*, so this should be **much** faster. As I said in my comment above, the bottleneck this way should actually be the parsing and output rather than the actual computation.

Comment: The question originally said t≤10. Now that it's been changed to t≤10⁴, I don't think the sparse representation makes sense anymore.

Answer (score -1):

Here's an algorithm with space and time complexity O(n)

I am using java since I am used to it

1) Create a hashset of n elements
2) Each time a watering is made increase the respective elements count
3) After file parsing is complete then iterate over hashset to calculate result.